# Multiple .gitignores in a single project

Tags: git, gitignore

I am having an issue managing my `.gitignore` file for a website I'm working on. I am storing my website on multiple repositories that require different files to be hidden or visible from git. For example: I don't want my Github repository to store images or database information. My production server on the other hand needs to see both of those, but I might not need some files I use for development purposes.

What's the best way to go about managing a `.gitignore` for multiple repositories?

Answer (score 4):

`.git/info/exclude` is a local-only `.gitignore`

If you store your patterns in there, it will only apply to that specific clone. `.gitignore` however, if committed to the repo, affects all repos equally.

[How do I tell git to ignore files?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_tell_git_to_ignore_files.3F)

> .git/info/exclude is local to your repository only, and not shared by
>   others who might fetch from your repository.
>   .gitignore is more
>   commonly used, as it can be checked into the repository and thereby
>   automatically shared with all users of the project.

Comment: Although it's common, the `.gitignore` file need not be committed to the repository. You can actually make it ignore itself, if you want.

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this. If I have a .gitignore in both the local repository and the Github repository, and I push to Github, It uses my local git ignore when I make commits correct? So does `.git/info/exclude` work the same way, or does it filter out incoming pushes?

Comment: @mcmullins: If you exclude files it will still pull them, because someone else has put them into the index. It will also track changes you make to it. But any new files you create that are not in the index will not be acknowledged. You can't help the fact that someone else has decided to track a type of file. You must share that aspect.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I changed a couple words to emphasis that it *can* be committed to the repo

Comment: alright ... I'm still having a hard time seeing how this will help me separate my file exclusions then since I will only ever be pushing from my local repository.

Comment: You can ignore your stuff. You cant ignore stuff that others decide to commit. It will get pulled down to you. I do this all the time with local test data. I dont want it pushed up. Then we have common shared ignores for thing we would all encounter like temp files.